# How to make table header and table footer appear on each page?

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf, export-to-pdf

The table footer and header only appear at the beginning and at the end of the page. I'm using FPDF.

**This is the code:**

```
$pdf = new myPDF();    
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{nb}');    
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4', 0);    
$pdf->headerTable();    
$pdf->viewTable($con);    
$pdf->footerTable();    
$pdf->Output();
```

This is myPDF class:

```
<?php
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_tc', 'root', '');
require('function.php');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class myPDF extends FPDF
{
    function header()
    {
        $this->SetleftMargin(30);
        $this->SetFont('Times', 'B', 14);
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Office 1', 0, 0, 'C');
        $this->Ln(20);

    }
    function footer()
    {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Times', '', 8);
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page ' . $this->PageNo() . '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C');
    }
    function headerTable()
    {
        $this->SetleftMargin(20);
        $this->SetFillColor(255, 213, 31);
        $this->SetDrawColor(50, 50, 100);
        $this->SetFont('Times', 'B', 12);
        $this->Cell(15, 10, 'Nomor', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Tanggal Cek', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Type Unit', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Serial Number', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Serial Number2', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(30, 10, 'Lokasi', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(30, 10, 'Ruangan', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Ln();
    }
    function footerTable()
    {
        $this->SetleftMargin(30);
        $this->SetFillColor(255, 213, 31);
        $this->SetDrawColor(50, 50, 100);
        $this->SetFont('Times', 'B', 12);
        $this->Cell(15, 10, 'Nomor', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Tanggal Cek', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Type Unit', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Serial Number', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Serial Number2', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(30, 10, 'Lokasi', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(30, 10, 'Ruangan', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Ln();
    }
    function viewTable($con)
    {
        $this->SetleftMargin(30);
        $this->SetFont('Times', '', 12);
        $this->SetFillColor(224, 224, 224);
        $stmt = $con->query("SELECT * FROM officepakai");
        while ($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $this->Cell(15, 10, $data->Nomor, 1, 0, 'C', true);
            $this->Cell(40, 10, $data->Tanggal_Cek, 1, 0, 'L', true);
            $this->Cell(40, 10, $data->Type_Unit, 1, 0, 'L', true);
            $this->Cell(40, 10, $data->Serial_Number, 1, 0, 'L', true);
            $this->Cell(40, 10, $data->Serial_Number2, 1, 0, 'L', true);
            $this->Cell(30, 10, $data->Lokasi, 1, 0, 'L', true);
            $this->Cell(30, 10, $data->Ruangan, 1, 0, 'L', true);
            $this->Ln();
        }
    }
}
$pdf = new myPDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{nb}');
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4', 0);
$pdf->headerTable();
$pdf->viewTable($con);
$pdf->footerTable();
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with this *lib* but as per [it's documentation here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm) I'd say only Header and Footer methods are being called, but you seem to have some customizations called `headerTable` and `footerTable`.

The `Header()` and `Footer()` methods are called automatically, so I believe that calling the custom methods inside them should do the trick:

```
function Header()
{
    $this->SetleftMargin(30);
    $this->SetFont('Times', 'B', 14);
    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Office 1', 0, 0, 'C');
    $this->Ln(20);
    $this->headerTable(); // add this
}

function Footer()
{
    $this->SetY(-15);
    $this->SetFont('Times', '', 8);
    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page ' . $this->PageNo() . '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C');
    $this->footerTable(); // add this
}
```